# java: how to append text in a String after a certain index

Tags: java, string

i have a path

```
C:\Users\abc xyz\Desktop\test.docx
```

I want to change in into

```
C:\Users\sara waheed\Desktop\~$sara.docx
```

for that first i got the last index of backslash now i want t append '~$' after the last backslash

```
String str=path.toString();
int index = str.lastIndexOf('\\');
```

**Note**
I do not know the value of the path in advance

how can i achieve that

Comment: Didn't you just ask that question like 15 minutes ago? Well anyway... if you know the index, you can cut out the neede parts with [`String#substring(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-). From there on, it should be simple string concatenation.

Comment: You just asked that question, were told how to do it, were given a link to the documentation, and then deleted your question. Don't be so lazy. Read the documentation, and try doing it. Or learn something other than programming, because reading documentation and trying to write code is what it's all about.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should use java.nio.file API when manipulating paths, so that it can avoid platform dependent assumptions.

```
String str = path.getFileName().toString();
// The string concatenation way:
if(str.endsWith(".docx")) { // should we check the beginning of fname?
                              // maybe it already has the prefix?
    path = path.resolveSibling("~$" + str);
}
System.out.println(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're representing files, I suggest using the [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) api. You can modify any part of the path without messing with the rest.

```
Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\abc xyz\\Desktop\\test.docx");
Path lock = file.resolveSibling("~$" + file.getFileName());
```

To interact with these paths, go ahead and look at the Files class.

```
Files.touch(lock);
```

Or alternatively using the classic way via `path.toFile()`

By the way, these are all in the `java.nio.file` package.